# Navigation based application without a uitableview error

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I do this:
First create navigation based application. 
Then delete `UITableView` from rootViewController.xib, add a `UIView` connect it to File's Owner.
Change `UITableView` to `UIViewController` in `RootViewcontroller.h` 
Finally clean all methods of `UITableView` in `RootViewcontroller.m`

But when I run the project receives this error:

```
-[RootViewcontroller tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:unreconized selector sent to instance
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibility.

1. Make sure that UITableView protocol is implemented in the header file.
   Eg `@interface TestingViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`
2. Check that your connection from in the Interface Builder and make sure its linked properly